# Comparison of Asp.net (MVC) and WPF (MVVM) - Is There a Data Binding Equivalent?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf, mvvm

I am considering a transition form WPF (mvvm) to asp.net (MVC). I thought it might be useful for sanity sake to draw a lose comparison of asp.net(MVC) and WPF(MVVM).

What would a MVC equivalent of the following WPF Example look like? To be specific, I am curious as to how the separation of UI and application logic is maintained and perhaps more importantly, if there is a data binding equivalent. How would the two different design patterns accomplish the same scenario.

**Viewmodel**

In your view model, you would have a class in which a component in the view will bind too. Something to the tune of:

```
namespace solution.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private DateTime _fromDate;

        public DateTime FromDate
        {
            get { return _fromDate; }
            set { _fromDate = value; OnPropertyChanged("FromDate"); }
        }

        private DateTime _toDate;

        public DateTime ToDate
        {
            get { return _toDate; }
            set { _toDate = value; OnPropertyChanged("ToDate");}
        }
    }
}
```

Where BaseViewModel is:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<Window .......>
    <Grid>
       <DatePicker SelectedDate = "{Binding ToDate}">
       <DatePicker SelectedDate = "{Binding FromDate}">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Comparing an MVC web app with a WPF desktop app is like comparing apples with cars. Do not make the mistake of trying to port it. Forget what you've done so far and start from scratch.

Comment: That's fair, and ultimately what I had in mind. Still was hoping to start a discussion as to how the different design paterns accomplish the same goals.

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look to http://knockoutjs.com It's a framework to develop Javascript UI using MVVM pattern.

Comment: I do both myself, and the only similarity between the two patterns is that in a webpage that relies heavily on ajax requests to handle things the user is doing in the UI, it is very beneficial to use a javascript MVVM like knockoutjs as @MartinoBordin mentioned.  They take care of all those fiddly UI <--> javascript updates for you, just like Bindings do in WPF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think some of the comments on this question so far are a little unfair...Yes the two technologies (ASP.Net MVC and WPF) are used to build for completely different platforms, but there are comparisons that can be made between the architectures (MVC and MVVM) being used in each of those platforms.

In WPF you have a *ViewModel* that exposes your *Model* to your *View*. In your example, `MainViewModel` exposes a model that contains a from and a to date via the `FromDate` and `ToDate` properties. The view can then choose to display those values as it pleases.

In ASP.Net MVC, you still have a *Model* and a *View* and something that connects the two - a *Controller*. The action invoked on your controller by some HTTP request is responsible for populating a model to be rendered by a view and returned to the client as an HTTP response.

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult ShowMeTheModel()
  {
    SimpleModel model = new SimpleModel
    {
      FromDate = DateTime.Today,
      ToDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7)
    };

    return View(model);
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult UpdateTheModel(SimpleModel model)
  {
    // use the model parameter to persist changes or otherwise        

    return Redirect("ShowMeAllTheModels");
  }
}
```

And a basic View

```
<h2>A Simple Model</h2>

<% using(Html.BeginForm("UpdateTheModel", "Main")) %>
<% { %>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>From Date</th>
      <th>To Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= Html.DatePickerFor(model => model.FromDate) %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= Html.DatePickerFor(model => model.ToDate) %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<% } %>
```

Databinding occurs in the post back - put very simply, an `[HttpPost]` action with a parameter of type `SimpleModel` will populate that model with the values contained in the HTTP post. That action can then use that values in that model to persist changes or trigger some action.

So yes the platforms are very different and you need to be fully aware of these differences, but there are definitely comparisons that can be made as I have outlined above.

Comment: Thank you Simon for taking the time to draw the comparison. Definitely helps in my understanding of MVC from the WPF/MVVM perspective..

Comment: This is incomplete.  Client side MVVM frameworks are common for applications that utilize ajax more than postbacks.  You're just covering the server side (which is important, but still...).

Answer (score 1):

No, No, No and...NO

WPF is run at client side and everything is happening on the client side. It keeps all the states and data in the same machine's memory.

MVC on the other hand runs on both the client and server side where the server does NOT store the state (you can read more about HTTP stateless) and the client/server does not share the same piece of memory or data.

So those are completely different technology targeting completely different use cases.

Classic ASP on the other hand is trying to simulate the behavior you described by using post back. Basically it is sending back all the user's action back to the server and the server can act correspondingly (such as change the value, disable button ect).

I would not recommend using it anymore since it is putting lots of unnecessary pressure on the server

Comment: OK, thank you Steve. I appreciate the input. Still learning a lot of this. Wasn't sure if there was an mvc way of initializing the model in the controller, set values, and then passing whatever values to the view. Then go back the other way when something is changed in the view. Sounds like I will be doing a lot of JavaScript.

Comment: if the server needs to know when the user's selection changed before the user hits submit then chances are you are doing it wrong. There might be some cases which this is valid (for example you only want to load something when it is requested), in that case you can look into API calls. But do remember the stateless nature of HTTP

Comment: @steve, if you need real time SPA you can use mvvm, viewmodel in the server, and the view with html and Javascript. There are frameworks for that.